# How to insert toViewController in a custom pop transition when not using a helper like interactionController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

This is a custom pop gesture for a `UINavigationController` that does not use a helper like `interactionController`. The pop transition is totally manual and it works great, except that I need to insert the `toViewController` below the `fromViewController` when the gesture begins. As this script is right now, the `toViewController` only appears after the gesture has successfully finished.

Is this where snapshot comes into play? I've never used it. Or should I just place the toViewController into the superview and then remove it after the gesture completes?

```
func popPanGestureHandler(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    guard let fromViewController = currentViewController,
        let toViewController = previousViewController else {
        return
    }

    let translation: CGPoint = gesture.translation(in: gesture.view)
    let velocity: CGPoint = gesture.velocity(in: gesture.view)

    switch gesture.state {

    case .began:

        // insert toViewController here
        fromViewController.view.center = CGPoint(x: fromViewController.view.center.x + translation.x, y: fromViewController.view.center.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

    case .changed:

        fromViewController.view.center = CGPoint(x: fromViewController.view.center.x + translation.x, y: fromViewController.view.center.y)
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: gesture.view)

        // force finish
        if fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x > (fromViewController.view.frame.width / 3) * 2 {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x = fromViewController.view.frame.width
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) in
                self.popViewController(animated: false)

            })

            gesture.isEnabled = false
            gesture.isEnabled = true

        }

    case .ended:

        // cancel
        if fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x < fromViewController.view.frame.width / 2 && velocity.x < 750 {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x = 0
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) in
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            })

            gesture.isEnabled = false
            gesture.isEnabled = true

        }

        // finish
        else if fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x >= fromViewController.view.frame.width / 2 {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x = fromViewController.view.frame.width
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) in
                self.popViewController(animated: false)
            })

            gesture.isEnabled = false
            gesture.isEnabled = true

        }

        // finish
        else if velocity.x >= 750 {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
                fromViewController.view.frame.origin.x = fromViewController.view.frame.width
            }, completion: {
                (finished: Bool) in
                self.popViewController(animated: false)
            })

            gesture.isEnabled = false
            gesture.isEnabled = true

        }

    default:
        break

    }

}
```